# Where to define Celery subtask queues

Tags: django, task, celery, task-queue, celerybeat

I have a pluggable app I'm developing for a Django system. In it, I have a task for creating notifications that looks something like so:

installable_app.tasks

```
@app.task(name='tasks.generate_notifications')
def generate_notifications(...):
```

I have a pluggable app I'm developing for a Django system. In it, I have a task for creating notifications that looks something like so:

installable_app.tasks

```
@app.task(name='tasks.generate_notifications')
def generate_notifications(...):
  clients = get_list_of_clients()
  for client in clients:
    client_generate_notification.delay(client['name'], client['id'])
  return "Notification Generation Complete"

@app.task
def client_generate_notification(client_name, client_id):
  ...
  return result
```

Now I want this to run periodically which can be accomplished with Celery Beat using settings. I also want it to be on its own queue:

settings.py:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE ={
  {'generate_schedule_notifications': {
     'task': 'tasks.generate_notifications',
     'schedule': crontab(hour=6, minute=0),
     'options': {'queue': 'notification_gen'},
     'args': ('schedule', 'Equipment', 'HVAC')},
  }
}
```

The first task, `generate_notifications` is run correctly on the queue `notification_gen` but the `client_generate_notification` subtasks are run on the default queue.

I know I can specify the queues specifically in the @task decorator but since this is a django app, I would rather they be specified where it is actually run.

I've looked into using the `CELERY_ROUTES` option but when I tried it, it seemed to overwrite the queues for other tasks I was running.

Is the best practice to define all the possible queues in `CELERY_ROUTES` or is there a better way to set up my task so that they will both run on the same queue?

Comment: Can you give the `CELERY_ROUTES` settings?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like [it](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#groups)?